# Using MachineFunction info in FunctionPass in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to gather some information from the backend to use in combination with the IR in LLVM. 
The problem is that I wrote a pass to collect the info as a MachineFunctionPass and now I want to use it in a FunctionPass, so I set the dependency using getAnalysisUsage. When I try to run the pass, it crashes due to maybe a dependency loop.
Is there a workaround this issue?

Thanks,